# What is an interval in $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Tags: measure-theory

What is an interval in $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Isn't interval just in $\mathbb{R}$ and higher dimensions have some sort of rectangle or cube?

Particularly [here](https://www.math.ualberta.ca/~xinweiyu/217.1.13f/217-20131031.pdf) it's said that:

> Let $I$ be a bounded closed interval in $\mathbb{R}^n$ .  Then $μ( \partial I ) = 0$.

Comment: It seems that in the paper you linked, the word *interval* is used for [*n-cell*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-cell_(mathematics)).

Comment: Have you taken a look at [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_(mathematics)#Multi-dimensional_intervals) ? They define an interval in $\mathbb{R}^n$ as a cartesian product of intervals in $\mathbb{R}$. All of the types of intervals of real numbers they give are contained in this definition of an interval in $\mathbb{R}$ : $I$ is an interval if and only if for all $a,b,c$ such that $a,c\in I$, $a<b<c$ implies $b\in I$.

Comment: A certain type of parallipiped  (or parallelepiped).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An interval $I$ in ${\mathbb{R}}^n$ is a set
$$
I = I_1 \times \ldots \times I_n\mbox{,}
$$
where $I_i$ is an interval in $\mathbb{R}$, $i = 1 , \ldots , n$, being "$\times$" the cartesian product for sets.

Comment: But $I_1 \times I_2$ is a rectangle for example. So why call it an interval?

Comment: mavavilj I guess it's because just saying "interval" is easier than worrying about using the right word for the n-dimensional object, like saying Cube instead of rectangle etc

Comment: Normally, mathematicians try to construct a theory that is common in all dimensions and therefore has the same name, but in particular different names are used when studying cases like $ n = 1, 2, 3 $, because they are the most interesting cases to make practice problems (calculus for derivates, integrals,...). For example, in differential geometry, a curve is not the same as a surface, but both are manifolds.